# SQL: Selecting value of cell based on the value of another cell

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

The WordPress database schema for Users is as follows:

```
TABLE wp_users
ID
user_login
user_pass
user_nicename
user_email
...

TABLE wp_usermeta
umeta_id
user_id
meta_key
meta_value
```

Now, it's the `wp_usermeta` table that I want to be able to write a SQL statement for.

In one row, `meta_key` is "first_name" ... how do I write a SQL query that will pull out the `meta_value` where `meta_key` is equal to "first_name"? This does not work:

`SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = "first_name";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = "first_name";
```

Notice you had `WHERE meta_value` instead of `WHERE meta_key`